# dompdf pdf creation problems with accented characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, pdf-generation, dompdf

i'm using the dompdf library with Codeigniter (php 5 ++) , everythings works great, but i'm still having problems with accented chracters when displaying the pdf.

it replaces all the à ò è ù etc .. with strange chars (non-utf8 chars).

the envoirment is globally utf-8 how can i debug/try solutions for this problem?

i tryed setting the content type via php before creating the pdf but nothing changes ... then the same html i put in pdf is saved in db and it looks ok, accented chars are ok so it's a main dompdf problem i think, which sets some strange encoding i think :P

anyone can help me debugging and fixing?

**[EDITED]**

this is the HTML example of pdf documents i'm creating.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
                 <head>
                 <meta http-equiv=“Content-Type” content=“text/html; charset=utf-8” /> 
                 <style type="text/css">
                 body{margin:0 auto;padding:0px;font-size:10px;font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;}
                 #wrapper{margin:30px;}
                 #logo{margin:2px;background-image:url(http://localhost/img/logo.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
                 #ricevuta{font-weight:bold;margin-top:4px;padding:5px;font-size:14px;}
                 #order-n{color:#fff;padding:3px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#785a3b;}
                 #address-order{background-color:#ebe0d5;padding:5px;}
                 .h1-p{font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;margin:5px;}
                 table{width:100%;}
                 table tr{width:100%;padding:4px;}
                 .align-right{text-align:right;}
                 thead {background-color:#785a3b;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;}
                 #table-total{background-color:#ebe0d5;}
                 </style>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                 <div id="wrapper">
                 <div id="logo">
                  <img src="http://localhost/img/logo.png" />
                 </div>
                 <div id="ricevuta">
                 Ricevuta Ordine
                 </div>
                <div id="order-n">
                 ORDINE numero - <strong>1 - Data (15-08-2011)</strong>
                </div>
                <p class="h1-p">Indirizzo Spedizione</p>
                <div id="address-order">
                <p>
                <strong></strong><br>
                <strong>sdfsdf sdfsd</strong><br>
                sfgfdg (sdgfdg), Austria, 45666<br>
                sdfsdf<br>
                telefono fisso: <br>
                telefono mobile: <br>
                 </p>
                 </div>
               <p class="h1-p">Riepilogo Ordine</p>
               <table>
               <thead>
               <tr>
               <td><strong>Nome Prodotto</strong></td>
               <td><strong>Codice Prodotto</strong></td>
               <td><strong>Quantita</strong></td>
               <td><strong>Prezzo</strong></td>
               </tr>
               </thead>

                    <tr>
                    <td>3423rf</td>
                    <td><strong># </strong></td>
                    <td><strong>2</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>29,70 euro</strong></td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
               <table id="table-total">
               <tr class="align-right">
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td><strong>Sub-totale:</strong> euro 59,40</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="align-right">
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td><strong> Spedizione:</strong> euro 26,50</td>
               </tr>

                <tr class="align-right">
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td><strong>Totale (tax,incluse):</strong> euro 85,90</td>
               </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                </body></html>
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode

Comment: didn't understand if i need to run or install packages via shell commands, in that way i can't cause i'm on a standard hosting. also tryed enabling the UNICODE support http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode#Configure_DOMPDF_for_Unicode_support  but it doesn't works :( and also i didn't founded the line DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED in the file specified in the doc :/ i added that but there wasn't and when added nothing changed :(

Comment: @MarcB ok i updated the dompdf to the latest version and UNICODE SUPPORT is enabled by default, the problem persist :( accented chars are converted to non-utf8 chars :(

Comment: If you've followed all the instructions at that page [you should be ok](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=1aca140f7f13bda3ca7fa3aecc2bb92d). Check the setup page in the sample site (.../dompdf/www/setup.php) to see if you have any configuration issues.

Comment: Also, a sample of your HTML doc would help.

Comment: @BrianS i checked the setup page and it says /dompdf/lib/ttf2ufm/ttf2ufm-src/ttf2pt1' is not readable   ... but that dir path doesn't exist :/ i founded dompdf/lib/ttf2ufm/ but inside there is no /ttf2ufm-src dir :O

Comment: @BrianS then didn't catched 1 thing about the ttf2ufm executable .. how can it works if i'm on a mac OS and his extension is .exe :|

Comment: @BrianS i tryed putting html with accented chars here dompdf/www/demo.php   and it works without problems with accented chars, i think problem is in the envoirment when sending html to the dompdf ... uhm

Comment: You don't need ttf2ufm unless you're loading new fonts into dompdf. If it works with the demo then you should be able to render your document correctly. Can you post the HTML you're testing with?

Comment: @BrianS yep i think so, anyway i edited the answer check the html is pretty simple, just texts are dinamically putted via php and in case of accented chars it returns strange chars in pdf

Comment: Looking at your HTML I would say you're probably having problems because of the font specified in your CSS. Currently the core PDF fonts (Helvetica, Times Roman, Courier) only support the Windows ANSI character set. Try using "Deja Vu Sans" ... that's what I used in the sample I posted.

Comment: @BrianS tryed man also tryed without specifying any font-family in CSS but the problem persist really i'm trying all i can :( it's so strange ... :(

Comment: @Ispuk you might try Deja Vu Sans (or one of the other Deja Vu fonts). These didn't make it into beta 2, but you can get them from the [code repository](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/checkout) (or [download a nightly](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my problem using `utf8_decode($html)` before passing `$html` to `dompdf`. This means that accented chars now work.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. `utf8_decode()` can be destructive of the text when characters can't be represented in iso-8859-1, but it sounds like you're not using characters that can't be handled. If you ever need to try with UTF8 again, the stable 0.6.0 release will have significant improvements in usability and functionality.